# XSL Transform query for rearranging an xml

Tags: xml

I have an xml in the following way:

Input:

```
<Records>
<Record Action="Delete" >
      <Tag1 Name="ID" >B</Tag1>
      <Tag2 Name="ParentID" >A</Tag2>
      <Name>MyName1</Name>
</Record>
<Record Action="Delete" >
      <Tag1 Name="ID" >D</Tag1>
      <Tag2 Name="ParentID" >C</Tag2>
      <Name>MyName1</Name>
</Record>
<Record Action="Delete" >
      <Tag1 Name="ID" >C</Tag1>
      <Tag2 Name="ParentID" >B</Tag2>
      <Name>MyName1</Name>
</Record>
<Record Action="Delete" >
      <Tag1 Name="ID" >A</Tag1>
      <Name>MyName1</Name>
</Record>
<Records>
```

Now I wanted to transform this xml using xsl so that I have the following output:

Expected output:

```
<Records>
<Record Action="Delete" >
      <Tag1 Name="ID" >A</Tag1>
      <Name>MyName1</Name>
</Record>
<Record Action="Delete" >
      <Tag1 Name="ID" >B</Tag1>
      <Tag2 Name="ParentID" >A</Tag2>
      <Name>MyName1</Name>
</Record>
<Record Action="Delete" >
      <Tag1 Name="ID" >C</Tag1>
      <Tag2 Name="ParentID" >B</Tag2>
      <Name>MyName1</Name>
</Record>
<Record Action="Delete" >
      <Tag1 Name="ID" >D</Tag1>
      <Tag2 Name="ParentID" >C</Tag2>
      <Name>MyName1</Name>
</Record>
<Records>
```

Basically the parents should come first then the children in the xml. (i.e. in this scenario A is the top most parent, B is the child of A, C is the child of B and D is the child of C)
The XML file is a large file and may go upto 2000 lines.
I was looking at the Meunchian method to see if that approach will work, but not sure if it would be a memory intensive operation.
Could you please suggest an xsl to do this transform. (in xsl 1.0)

Thanks in advance,
Gok.

Comment: What have you done so far? We'll be glad to help you debug, but if you want us to write it all for you that's really not what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this general problem would be first to chase up the chains to find the root of the tree -- I hope there is just one -- and then to recursively process downward, looking for records whose parent is the current node and processing them.

HOWEVER: I don't consider either your input, or your output, to be a particularly good use of XML. If you want X to be the child of Y, why not make it the child in the XML sense as well and put Y inside X? XML is hierarchical; take advantage of that.